# MongoDB / C# - Inserting document with an automatically populated timestamp

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to insert into a MongoDB collection.

I have a data model containing an Id (ObjectId) and a Timestamp (long) as the first two properties.

From here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps I understand that if these are both null, they should get automatically populated?

When Saving the entity, the ObjectId (Id/_id) column is being set, although the timestamp remains null. Is there something special i need to do set set this?

I've tried:

```
    newdoc= Update.Replace(doc.ToBsonDocument().Set("Timestamp", new BsonJavaScript("new Timestamp()")));
    db.mydocs.Save(newdoc);
```

But then get "GetDocumentId method cannot be called on a UpdateWrapper." exception.

Can anybody point me in right direction?

Thanks in advance

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Time stamp has to be one of the first two fields in you object, otherwise it will not get filled.

Comment: yeah, that's kind of my problem. my mapped class (POCO object) has a string Id {get;set;} and long TimeStamp {get;set;} as first two props

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other hidden fields? _id or something inserted by your framework. Did you view the entries by running mongo shell to check?

Comment: Hi ivo, yes I used the mongo shell app.  First two properties are _id and Timestamp. (using db.collection.find() I can see in the document object.) in the link I posted it references using "new Timestamp()" any other thoughts / ideas? Thanks

Comment: First check that it works manually in mongo shell. "db.foo.insert({x:new Timestamp() } )" and then "db.foo.find()", you should see "x" : { "t" : 1232423523523532, "i" : 1 } }. This would confirm that mongodb does indeed populate the timestamp automatically. If this is the case, then there is something wrong with your POCO object. I don't use C# so can't really help there.

Comment: thanks for comment, no resolution to it. I changed solution to use integer sequence. +1 for response but didn't answer question. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't really find an answer in the internet, so it took some time to figure out how to do it. Solution appears to be quite trivial. When I tried to type `new Timestamp()` in the console it returned `Timestamp(0, 0)` which was a hint to me. All you need to do is:

```
doc.Timestamp = new BsonTimestamp(0, 0);
```

Which will make server set the value of the timestamp for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Use C# native DateTime Library
var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

//Filter 
var filter = builder.Eq("SomeKey", "SomeValue");

//What needs to be updated
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update                  
.Set("createdAt", dateTime);

//Upsert Option!
var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

collection.UpdateMany(filter, update, options)

//Out Put
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-12-21T19:25:22.471Z")
```